# What is a ProfileService/When is a ProfileService executed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I've been playing with IdentityServer4. Absolutely love it.

I've been going through the tutorials on your site, specifically https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html

I have created a Profile Service that does the following:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("test-claim", "test-value"));
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        context.IsActive = true;

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

This works great, my custom claim is visible in the log window of my JS client.

I put a break point on it just to inspect what is in the context, and I noticed it was getting hit twice. The caller properties were `ClaimsProviderAccessToken` and `UserInfoEndpoint` respectively. Why is this?

In my naivety I removed the `profile` scope from my js client, and in oidc-js config also removed the profile scope, and set `loadUserInfo: false` yet my `ProfileService` it is still called twice.

If my end goal is to set claims based on parameters from a database, I really I don't want to be doing this operaion twice, do I? (Genuine question -- I don't know). A 'solution' would be to only set them on "ClaimsProviderAccessToken" but there is something telling me that there will be a reason ProfileServices get called twice and that there is some importance of it setting the claims on both runs through.

Comment: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` is only, if you want the commands to be available in with dotnet command, i.e. `dotnet ef database update`. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` is stil there and available, but will only be available in package manager console (Powershell commands, like `Migration-Add` or `Database-Update` as it was used in previous versions of EF, like EF6). Also see http://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/208

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The profile service is called whenever IdentityServer needs to return claims about a user to a client applications.

If you request an identity and access token - it will get called twice (since you might be putting different claims into each token type).